Strategies for spotting changes inside moved or renamed files in git
You know that scenario, it happened to you a thousand times :

You have moved and renamed a file.
Then you have modified it.
After committing, you to need to cross fingers for git to detect that it's actually the same file (that part usually goes well)
You create a PR for a series of commits containing that moving/renaming
You want to review the changes (by using tools such as gitlab or others).
Problem: the two versions of the file (the deleted one and the new one containing the modifications) will still appear separately (despite having a nice little label warning you that the file got moved) and the modifications will still be hard to spot because the entire file appears as new (it's all green).

What are ways of mitigating this?
The only solution I found so far is self-discipline: Enforce commits containing ONLY the file moving and renaming. Zero modification allowed. Leave that for a subsequent commit. Even better : Do the move/rename in an entirely separate PR (so that the actual changes are still easily visible in the "all changes" view of gitlab or other tools)
The difficulty with that approach is that it adds some overhead. Another problem is reluctant devs who don't want to comply to that or forget to do it, because they can't see that it was much easier for them to see the changes in a moved file at the time they committed than for the reviewer reading the final result.
Do you know of any other way?

Not use Github as the diff viewer? git diff and gitk work quite well.

I would add a third argument to doing the rename and modification separately: simplicity and ease of review. Since class names and the like are often tied to file names, renaming a file means renaming a class which can have a broad impact on the code. A major refactoring like that plus a bug fix/feature change is a lot to review. Separate them into two PRs and it will go better. if you can't get devs to follow that, that's a process issue for your team.

"The difficulty with that approach is that it adds some overhead."… that's overhead other vcs's pay every time, don't worry about it, you're doing renames that much, pay for the explicit tracking.

yes you are right its either being deciplined or working with built in UI in your editor but if you find your self in a such situation then i hope this helps :

Configure Git to better detect moves and copies

git config --global diff.renames true
git config --global diff.renameLimit 999999

For reviewing changes in moved files:

Show the diff of a moved file, ignoring the move itself
git diff --color-moved=blocks --find-renames

Alternative: Use git log with -M and -C options

git log -M -C --stat --follow path/to/file

For reviewing specific commits with moved files:

git show --color-moved=blocks commit_hash

To see the actual content changes in a moved file:

git diff --color-moved=blocks HEAD^..HEAD path/to/new/file

For more detailed move detection:

git diff --find-renames=90% --break-rewrites

To generate a patch that preserves move information:

git format-patch --find-renames --break-rewrites HEAD^

For branch comparison with move detection:

git diff branch1...branch2 --color-moved=blocks --find-renames

Thank you for the great answer. It's not exactly what I'm looking for as my question is more focused on helping the reviewer(s) (who can be juniors and struggle with git a little bit) but I absolutely love it as a reference for future work.
